# Should I replace a receptacle with a small burn mark?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have a window A/C in my room. I turned it on last night and power from that socket, the restroom lights, second bedroom and hallway lights are not working now. The plugs in the restroom do work. The socket that the A/C unit was plugged into has a slight burn mark on it. No breakers tripped and I checked the whole house for GFCI plugs to reset.

What else could I try? Should I replace the socket that has the burn mark because I can't find any other problem?

Comment: Are you sure the breaker isn't tripped? Most breaker handles don't move all the way to the off position when they trip. If you push the handle towards the ON position, if there is any give (the handle moves slightly) the breaker is tripped. Move the handle to the OFF position, then back to the ON position to reset the breaker.

Comment: I went thru every switch turned every single one to the off position then to the on position. Did it 3 times after trying the lights a few times

Comment: Unfortunately it's difficult to diagnose electrical faults through the internet. Your best bet might be to contact a local licensed Electrician.

Comment: If there is a sign of a burn mark on the socket or any electrical outlet they should be changed and the breaker should be checked. (may be the wrong breaker / socket.) If you can deal with them off I would wait till an electrician gets there and let him/her test it and diagnose it for you.

Comment: Little burn mark on the front, big burn mark on the back where they used the push-in slots, the connection lost tension, heated and eventually failed. And it's probably the first socket in the daisy chain. Not the first time I've seen this happen, sockets now come with three way connects, push-in, u bent wire end under the screw head and straight wire end under the screw plate all on the same socket. Use the most mechanically sound method for the first socket in the string (not push-in).

Comment: Rule #1:  There is no such thing as a small burn mark on electrical wiring.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely replace it if you feel comfortable doing so. A small burn mark on the surface could be a big burn or melted spot on the back. If it was quick-wired (wires just stuck in the holes in the back) then it is quite likely the contact is compromised or even burnt.